# Number of the same anonymous class(TypeReference) declarations

Tags: java, jackson, classloader, anonymous-class

I'm working on a project where we have to deal with a number of JSON entities and an SDK to make calls for that JSONs. To map JSON to DTO we use the Jackson library and TypeReference class.

Let's say there is a Repository do deal with a certain type of JSONs and there are methods that use `new TypeReference` under that hood.

```
class Repository {
   a() {
      new TypeReference<MyDto> {}
   }

   b() {
      new TypeReference<MyDto> {}
   }

}
```

It would create next classes after build:

```
Repository$1.class
Repository$2.class
```

Basically, I have 2 global questions :

1. Would the number of declarations of the same TypeReference affect somehow my project? Because there would be generated .class files for each declaration. Would it affect a classloader?
2. Would you suggest any best practices to deal with TypeReference? Should I put them into a dedicated util class? Should it be a singleton instance of TypeReference or it doesn't make any sense to have it as a singleton?

Move to util class to prevent over-creating of .class files.

Comment: Unless you have thousands of these, it won't make big difference. But why are you creating several anonymous classes if you can just create a `class TypeReferenceImpl<T> extends TypeReference<T>` and then use that everywhere? Or is there a need for multiple subclasses?

Comment: @f1sh that’s obviously a type token intended to capture the generic type. Hence, it must be a reifiable type to fulfill the purpose. A `TypeReferenceImpl<T>` does not work. A shared `class MyDtoTypeReference extends TypeReference<MyDto>` on the other hand, would do.